# First executeScript() of selenium-webdriver costs too much time for phantomjs

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

It seems the first execution of the web driver below takes 3~4 seconds for the response, even for the most naive ones.

**Question**

Can anyone suggest a way to change my code to improve the response time of my web driver?

```
var webdriver = require("selenium-webdriver");

var driver = new webdriver.Builder().withCapabilities(capabilities)
    .usingServer()
    .forBrowser("phantomjs")
    .build();
var t1 = new Date().getTime();
console.log("start1 " + t1);
driver.executeScript("return 0;").then(function(res)  {

    var t2 = new Date().getTime();
    console.log("start2 " + t2);
    console.log("It costs " + (t2-t1));
});
```

Comment: Your variable `t1` holds the time before the driver is launched. Thus the `3~4 seconds` is the time to launch the browser + `executeScript`.

Comment: Does it take so much time for the browser to launch? If so, can I launch it in another call? I really don't want it to hold me in executing the scripts.